# Day of the week, Month and Number of Day in Text

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to display the Day of the Week, Month and Number of Day in Text in Flutter like so : "Today is Monday February 4th". I tried using the dart package intl but its not working.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@AmitJangid has an answer for you,
But there is no inbuilt function to add the suffix.

You can add it using below code:

```dart
formatDate() {
  var date = DateTime.now();
  var suffix = "th";
  var digit = DateTime.now().day % 10;
  if ((digit > 0 && digit < 4) && (date.day < 11 || date.day > 13)) {
    suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][digit - 1];
  }
  return DateFormat("EEEE MMMM d'$suffix'").format(DateTime.now());
}
```

In your Text Widget,

```dart
Text(
  "Today is " + formatDate(),
),
```

You will get:

Today is Thursday February 7th

Answer (score 4):

To format date you are using the right package. You just have to pass the correct date format to get the desired result.

[Check the flutter docs for DateFormat class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

An Example for this would be:

```
var _formattedDate = DateFormat('EEEE MMMM dd').format(DateTime.now());
print(_formattedDate);
```

The result for above code is: **Thursday February 07**

If you want to add the suffix as well, then you can try this..

```
if (_formattedDate.endsWith('1')) {
  _formattedDate += 'st';
} else if (_formattedDate.endsWith('2')) {
  _formattedDate += 'nd';
} else if (_formattedDate.endsWith('3')) {
  _formattedDate += 'rd';
} else {
  _formattedDate += 'th';
}

print(_formattedDate);
```

The result for above code is: **Thursday February 07th**